# How to Reshape Dataset and Extract Dates, HbA1c, and Months for Analysis?

Tags: r

Newbie to R!

I have a dataset which looks like this.

```
 Df <- structure(list(Pat_ID = c("1123", "1134", "1138", "1139"),
               study_group = c("1", "1", "0", "0"),
               days_1 = c("-329", "-261", "0", "-165"),
               HbA1c_Date_1 = c("11/7/2018", "31/10/2018", "28/8/2019", "17/05/2019"),
               HbA1c_1= c("8.8", "7", "11.1", "10.1" ),
               days_2= c("-196", "-168", "NA", "0"),
               HbA1c_Date_2= c("3/20/2019", "01/02/2019", "NA", "29/10/19"),
               HbA1c_2= c("9.1", "7.7", "NA", "11.9"),
               days_3= c("-105", "0", "NA", "85"),
               HbA1c_Date_3= c("6/19/2019","27/02/2019", "NA", "22/01/2020"),
               HbA1c_3= c("9.1", "11.1", "NA", "8.4"),
               days_4= c("0", "89", "NA", "NA"),
               HbA1c_Date_4= c("10/2/2019", "19/07/2019", "NA", "NA"),
               HbA1c_4= c("9.2", "10.1", "NA", "NA"),
               days_5= c("97", "168", "NA", "NA"),
               HbA1c_Date_5= c("1/7/2020", "16/10/2019", "NA", "NA"),
               HbA1c_5= c("9.1", "8.1", "NA", "NA" ),
               baseline = c("0", "0", "0", "0"),
               followup_1 = c("97", "89", "NA", "85"),
               followup_2 = c("NA", "168", "NA", "NA"),
               followup_3 = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
               followup_4 = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
               followup_5 = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
               followup_6 = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
               followup_7 = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
               X0_month = c("1", "1", "1", "1"),
               X1_month = c("0", "0", "0", "NA"),
               X2_month = c("0", "0", "0", "NA"),
               X3_month = c("0", "1", "0", "NA"),
               X4_month = c("1", "0", "0", "1"),
               X5_month = c("0", "0", "0", "NA"),
               X6_month = c("0", "1", "0", "NA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

This is a sample dataset.

Where:

PAt_ID is a unique patient ID.
Study_group indicates Intervention group (1) or Comparator group (0).
HbA1c_Date_1, HbA1c_Date_2, etc., are dates when HbA1c tests were performed.
HbA1c_1, HbA1c_2, etc., are corresponding HbA1c values.
days_1, days_2, etc., represent the time difference from an index date.
baseline contains baseline days (derived from the days_ columns with value 0).
followup_1, followup_2, etc., represent days from the baseline.
_month columns are categorical, indicating in which month a visit occurred.

The output dataset will focus on "baseline", "followup", and "*month" columns. The "baseline" and "followup*" columns contains number of days (extracted from the "days_" column). I want R  to scan "days_" columns and extract respective HbA1c Date and HbA1c Value for the respective number of days for each patient. As my original dataset is transposed/ wide I want it to be long.
I need to reshape this dataset to create a new one with the following structure:

| Pat_ID | study_group | HbA1c Date | HbA1c | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1123 | 1 | 10/2/2019 | 9.2 | 0_month |
| 1123 | 1 | 1/7/2020 | 9.1 | 4_month |
| 1134 | 1 | 27/02/2019 | 11.1 | 0_month |
| 1134 | 1 | 19/07/2019 | 10.1 | 3_month |
| 1134 | 1 | 16/10/2019 | 8.1 | 6_month |
| 1138 | 0 | 28/08/2019 | 11.1 | 0_month |
| 1139 | 0 | 29/10/19 | 11.9 | 0_month |
| 1139 | 0 | 22/01/2020 | 8.9 | 4_month |

I tired For loop but it did not work well for me.

Comment: `Error: unexpected input in: "  followup_7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA),   0_"`

Comment: I have edited my sample dataset. Even if the error persist could help me know where it is?

Comment: @Ray I believe you want your dates in "quotes" and perhaps in Date format. It is often preferable to use `dput(head(sampledata))` and copy/paste the result into your question, to make the data reproducible. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for details on how to make a great reproducible example in R.

Comment: I have edited my sample data code. I think it should be reproducible. If the error still persist let me know. Thank you for your support.

Comment: @Ray Thanks for providing the sample data. See solution below and see if this helps you moving forward.

Comment: @Ben It worked! Your code is awesome! Thank you so much! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to help you get started.

Instead of using loops, you can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` (part of tidyverse) to put into long format. A pattern will focus on dates and A1c values ending with a number. The `values_transform` will put days into a numeric format - but will throw a warning as there are "NA" character values instead of `NA` symbols in that column.

It looks like you only want to keep A1c values beyond 0 days, so a `filter` can remove those lab values prior to baseline assessment. Next, a `mutate` will add a counter for each A1c value for a given patient.

The ending result will be joined using with a second data.frame derived from the `X0_month` through `X6_month` data, so it can be treated a bit differently. Here, you can put into longer format with `pivot_longer` again, but then `filter` where the value is "1" (and leave out "0"). A counter again can be applied within each patient.

After joining, the `select` will allow you to include the columns of interest (in the order you want).

I did not address other formatting issues (dates not in date format, and months might be better as a numeric month value).

```
library(tidyverse)

Df |>
  pivot_longer(cols = -Pat_ID, 
               names_to = c(".value", "time"), 
               names_pattern = "(\\w+)_(\\d+)", 
               values_transform = list(days = as.numeric), 
               values_drop_na = TRUE) |>
  filter(days >= 0) |>
  mutate(time_point = row_number(), .by = Pat_ID) |>
  inner_join(
    Df |>
      select(Pat_ID, study_group, X0_month:X6_month) |>
      pivot_longer(-c(Pat_ID, study_group), names_to = "Month") |>
      filter(value == "1") |>
      mutate(time_point = row_number(), .by = Pat_ID),
    by = c("Pat_ID", "time_point")
  ) |>
  select(Pat_ID, study_group, HbA1c_Date, HbA1c, Month)
```

**Output**

```
  Pat_ID study_group HbA1c_Date HbA1c Month   
  <chr>  <chr>       <chr>      <chr> <chr>   
1 1123   1           10/2/2019  9.2   X0_month
2 1123   1           1/7/2020   9.1   X4_month
3 1134   1           27/02/2019 11.1  X0_month
4 1134   1           19/07/2019 10.1  X3_month
5 1134   1           16/10/2019 8.1   X6_month
6 1138   0           28/8/2019  11.1  X0_month
7 1139   0           29/10/19   11.9  X0_month
8 1139   0           22/01/2020 8.4   X4_month
```